# Munging text strings with okinas and other Hawaiian diacritical marks

Tags: r, encoding, data-cleaning

I am using R to clean street addresses from Hawaii. The addresses have been inputed with [Hawaiian diacritical marks](https://www.hawaii.edu/site/info/diacritics.php). When using R on an OSX operating system, I can easily use gsub() to remove the diacritics; however, PC running 64-bit Windows machines running R show strange characters, such as "â€" in place of the okina (‘). I suspect it could be an encoding issue, and have included the encoding parameter like the following:

```
address_file <- read.csv("file.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Although most of the strange encoding was solved, R no longer could recognize certain diacritics such as the okina. For example, I would use the following syntax, but the okina will not be removed:

```
gsub("‘", "", hiplaces$name)
```

Can someone please help with solving this issue on a PC running 64-bit Windows. I suspect it could be 1) an encoding issue and I am choosing the incorrect encoding, or 2) a gsub solution that can remove/replace diacritics. The data I am trying to clean looks something like below:

```
hiplaces <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
hiplaces$name <- c("‘Imiola Congregational Church", "‘Ōla‘a First Hawaiian    Congregational Church", "Nā‘ālehu Community Center")

gsub("‘", "", hiplaces$name)
```

TIA.

Comment: @Pascal My apologies. A computer running 64-bit Windows (7 to be specific).

Comment: Your example works with locale set as `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your end result is a set of street addresses, you should be OK with simply retaining only alphanumeric characters.  Under this assumption, the following should work:

```
hiplaces <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
hiplaces$name <- c("‘Imiola Congregational Church",
                   "‘Ōla‘a First Hawaiian    Congregational Church",
                   "Nā‘ālehu Community Center")

hiplaces$name <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "", hiplaces$name)

> hiplaces$name
[1] "Imiola Congregational Church"
[2] "Olaa First Hawaiian    Congregational Church"
[3] "Naalehu Community Center"
```